# Accessing AWS s3 V2 bucket using V4 signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket which I could access using PUT/GET successfully with V2 signing process. However, I could only do a PUT with V4 signing process successfully but not able to GET it using V4. Please educate me on this.

Comment: Does your bucket have the correct access policies?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "V2 bucket". Show your bucket policy, your IAM role, and the command or code you are using.